# Renaming files using batch and regex

Tags: regex, batch-file, file-rename

I haven't really messed with batch files much, but given our work environment, it is our only solution.

We have a bunch of files with the following format:

```
ICN-A10-C-232101-H-8X662-00001-A-05-U
ICN-A10-C-232101-H-8X662-00002-A-01-U
ICN-A10-C-232101-H-8X662-00003-A-00-U
ICN-A10-C-232101-H-8X662-00004-A-92-U
```

and we need to remove the last digit set and following hyphen so they read like:

```
ICN-A10-C-232101-H-8X662-00001-A-U
ICN-A10-C-232101-H-8X662-00002-A-U
ICN-A10-C-232101-H-8X662-00003-A-U
ICN-A10-C-232101-H-8X662-00004-A-U
```

Again, a *.bat file looks like our only solution.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this somewhat strange trick:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

cd files
for %%a in (*) do (
   set "name=%%a"
   for %%b in ("!name:-=.!") do for %%c in ("%%~Nb") do (
      set "newName=%%~Nc%%~Xb"
      ECHO ren %%a !newName:.=-!
   )
)
```

That is, change `-` by `.` and use two nested FOR commands to eliminate the last two extensions. Then, reassemble the remaining name with the original extension and change back the dot by hypens:

```
C:\> dir /B files
ICN-A10-C-232101-H-8X662-00003-A-00-U
ICN-A10-C-232101-H-8X662-00002-A-01-U
ICN-A10-C-232101-H-8X662-00001-A-05-U
ICN-A10-C-232101-H-8X662-00004-A-92-U

C:\> test
ren ICN-A10-C-232101-H-8X662-00003-A-00-U ICN-A10-C-232101-H-8X662-00003-A-U
ren ICN-A10-C-232101-H-8X662-00002-A-01-U ICN-A10-C-232101-H-8X662-00002-A-U
ren ICN-A10-C-232101-H-8X662-00001-A-05-U ICN-A10-C-232101-H-8X662-00001-A-U
ren ICN-A10-C-232101-H-8X662-00004-A-92-U ICN-A10-C-232101-H-8X662-00004-A-U
```

Comment: +2 for obscurity and double nested FOR loops in DOS :-)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, no regex

```
for /f "tokens=1-11 delims=-" %%a in ('
    dir /b /a-d *
') do if "%%k"=="" if not "%%j"=="" (
  echo ren "%%a-%%b-%%c-%%d-%%e-%%f-%%g-%%h-%%i-%%j" "%%a-%%b-%%c-%%d-%%e-%%f-%%g-%%h-%%j"
)
```

rename operations are only echoed to console. If the output is correct, remove the `echo` command.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `rename` command on the directory where the files you want to rename are located.

```
rename 's/\d+-(?=\D*$)//' *
```

The above regex would match the number plus the following `-` symbol only if it's followed by zero or more non-digit characters and the end of the line anchor.

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/lS2uM2/2)

Comment: `rename` is lovely in Linux, but it's not included in Windows without cygwin or gnuwin32.  The `batch-file` tag is intended for Windows batch scripting.  I can't fault your suggestion, though.  I very frequently ssh to my linux box just so I can navigate back to my Windows filesystem over autofs and use the Linux `rename` utility.  I've never had much luck with the cygwin version.

Comment: Yeah, if we were using Linux. But no. :( Regex is easy.